# error while extending existential class

Tags: scala, existential-type

Let test simple construction:

```
case class ListRef (list : List[_]) extends ref.WeakReference(list)
```

It gives error:

```
<console>:8: error: illegal inheritance;
self-type ListRef does not conform to scala.ref.WeakReference[List[_$1]]'s selftype  scala.ref.WeakReference[List[_$1]]
   case class ListRef (list : List[_]) extends WeakReference(list)
```

What does it mean and how can it be escaped?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what that error message means but escaping it seems  pretty straightforward.

```
case class ListRef[A](list: List[A]) extends ref.WeakReference(list)
```

Comment: It require adding type argument.

Comment: Yes. What are you going for? Why do you do not want the type argument?